# icCube join table with ETL

Tags: iccube

I have a Customers table which contains the salesRepEmployeeNumber which is in the Employees table.

How do I do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Customers 
JOIN   Employees 
  ON   Customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber = Employees.employeeNumber
```

with icCube ETL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in another answer, you can add a table based in an SQL statement that would do the job. In case your original datasource is not able to do a join :

We've not yet an join transformation, added this in our [todo](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-230) list. On the meantime, what you can do is.

Create an Union Table with your two tables. This will create a new table with the columns of both tables. Put the small one, first as we're going to cache it later on.

Create a Javascript view, you might need to activate Javascript in your icCube.xml configuration. In this one you can cache the first table and use a bit of js to do the join. You can trigger the table change on a field being empty. Don't forget to put 'Table Row Ordering' to Keep Table Order.

hope it helps

Comment: May I suggest the Sean Kandel's paper [link](http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/wrangler) in order to put an finite upper bound to your todo list regarding ETL. Basically you need only 5 transformations: Map, Lookup (join), Reshape (normalize/denormalize), Positional (lag, fill,...), Sorting&Aggregtation. I would personally add one more: historization.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the ETL.

With the designer, add a table with the + sign in the menu above DataSource. The next panel gives you the choice between reading data from an existing table or an sql query.