# Table for hierachy in icCube

Tags: iccube

In icCube the table is an attribute of the dimension not of the hierarchy. This means that you cannot have two hierarchies defined on different tables.

How would you put in a single dimension the two following tables ?

`Table monthly:
date       year quarter month_nr    month  day
1997-01-01 1997   Q1       1      January   1 
1997-01-02 1997   Q1       1      January   2 
1997-01-03 1997   Q1       1      January   3 
1997-01-04 1997   Q1       1      January   4 
1997-01-05 1997   Q1       1      January   5`

`Table weekly:
date       year week_nr    day    day_nr
1997-01-01 1997   2     Wednesday     3 
1997-01-02 1997   2     Thursday      4 
1997-01-03 1997   2     Friday        5 
1997-01-04 1997   2     Saturday      6 
1997-01-05 1997   3     Sunday        7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use a join to merge both table so the final table looks like :

`Table monthly:
date       year quarter month_nr    month  month_day week_nr    day       day_nr
1997-01-01 1997   Q1       1      January   1            2     Wednesday     3 
1997-01-02 1997   Q1       1      January   2            2     Thursday      4 
1997-01-03 1997   Q1       1      January   3            2     Friday        5 
1997-01-04 1997   Q1       1      January   4            2     Saturday      6 
1997-01-05 1997   Q1       1      January   5            3     Sunday        7`

If you can't make a join on the database, feel free to check this other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782295/iccube-join-table-with-etl)
Or use a table wizard dimension that can create this kind of structures automatically.